# Reference a child table from another table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design

So I'm using TPT (Table per Type) in EntityFramework 6 to create a table hierarchy, assume something like this one:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommonProperty { get; set; } 
} 

public class ModelA: Model
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB: Model
{
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need to reference the table ModelA from itself, so that it contains reference to entities of the same type, something like this:

```
public class ModelA: Model
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public int ModelAId { get; set;

    public ModelA ModelA;
}
```

Now, this reference obviously refers to the Model table and not the ModelA, as this one technically doesn't have it's own Id.

**How can I do this?**

I've been thinking about adding a new internal int called ModelAId and refer to that one, but I don't know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, this reference obviously refers to the Model table and not the
>   ModelA, as this one technically doesn't have it's own Id.

You are forgetting that (at least according to your given example code) since ModelA inherits from Model, it now also has its own Id and CommonProperty attribute.

Comment: I understand your point. But what I need is to ensure that ModelAId **EXCLUSIVELY** refers to an entity of ModelA, and never one of ModelB.

Comment: This is basic OO. When you define ModelB:Model it is really distinct from ModelA. Another example, if you'd define a ModelB property in the ModelB class then you have to face facts that ModelB.ModelB.ModelB.Id is non-existent unless you've instantiated everything in the correct order.

Comment: If you say it is basic OO then you don't understand the question. It has nothing to do with polymorphism. I'm asking how to reference the table from itself with an Id and make sure that Id cannot be one that references the table ModelB.

Comment: I will update my answer but I was not referring to polymorphism here.